# Tkinter field in blank for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need your help to figure out how to make the following coding:

My idea is to get a message if fields `name` and `quantity` are in blank at the time I execute a function through a button. I printed what is the value if name and quantity are in blank and program says it is         `.!entry` and  `.!entry2` respectively.

Unfortunately it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

```
if name == .!entry and quantity == .!entry2:
    message = Label(root, text = 'Name and Quantity required' , fg = 'red')
    message.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)            
    return
```

Comment: do you mean that you only want to run the code when both entries have not been filled in?
When both entries are empty?

Comment: Exactly, when both entries are not filled in or empty. Thanks :D

Comment: use `if entry1.get() == "" and entry2.get() == "":` to check if it is empty or not.
(replace `entry1` and `entry2` to your own entry variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JordyvanDongen pointed out in the comments you should use `entry.get()` to get the text inside the the entry object.

I suggest this for you code, assuming the entry objects are named `name` and `quantity`:

```
if not name.get() or not quantity.get():
    message = Label(root, text = 'Both name and quantity are required', fg = 'red')
    message.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W + E)            
    return None
```

I changed the conditional to `or` so that if either of the fields are blank it will be triggered but you may want to change it back to `and` depending on your purposes..

Comment: Thanks :D Understood